InfoCenter в Eclipse
Прочитав официальную документацию Eclipse про InfoCenter я смог запустить его в браузере, но у меня возникла проблема: не получается убрать документацию Eclipse, которая появляется там по умолчанию, а также не могу понять как добавить туда мою документацию из моего плагина Help.
Я пробовал решить данную проблему с помощью plugin_customization.xml и helpData.xml, но никаких изменений нет.
Содержание файлов:
helpData:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<helpData>
    <toc id="exampleId"/>
    <extensions>
        <tocOrder>
            <toc id="/com.aviatron.help.mega/toc.xml"/>
        </tocOrder>
    </extensions>
</helpData>

plugin_customization:
org.eclipse.help.base/windowTitlePrefix=false
org.eclipse.help.base/linksView=false
org.eclipse.help.base/help_home=com.aviatron.help.mega/html/toc.html
org.eclipse.help/HELP_DATA=PLUGINS_ROOT/helpData.xml
org.eclipse.help/ignoredTOCS=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/toc.xml,/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/toc.xml,/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/toc.xml

Команда которой я запускал InfoCenter:
java -classpath .\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.help.base-4.2.100.jar org.eclipse.help.standalone.Infocenter -command start -eclipsehome C:\Users\BestUser\eclipse\java-2024-09\eclipse -plugincustomization .\eclipse\plugins\com.aviatron.help.mega\plugin_customization.ini -port 8888 -refresh  -consoleLog 


а что насчёт предыдущих ваших вопросов на ту же тему? 1 и 2

я пробую в данный момент разные способы, пока все неудачно
